Applying $\mu$ -Operator for Unbounded minimization
I'm learning how to use the $\mu$-Operator for unbounded minimization and trying to define a partial recursive function $g(y,z)$ from the primitive recursive function $f$ defined as:
$$
f(x, y, z) = \begin{cases} z - x \cdot y, & \text{if } z \geq x \cdot y, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
I understand that I need to find the minimum value of $x$ where the function $f(x,y,z) = 0$ and that for every $n \in N$ where $n < x$ the function should be defined. However, my problem lies in incorporating the variables $y$ and $z$ into this process.
I've searched online for resources on this topic but haven't found any that effectively address cases involving more than two variables. Could anyone recommend any resources or provide guidance on handling these additional variables?
Thanks in advance!

Let $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $z \in \mathbb{N}$. If $f \left( x , y , z \right)$ is defined for every $x \le n$ so that $f \left( n , y , z \right) = 0$ and, for all $i < n$, $f \left( i , y , z \right) > 0$ then $n = \mu \left( f \right) \left( y , z \right)$. That is, $y$ and $z$ are just parameters.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_recursive_function might be a source you want.

Thank you, so in my case a solution should be like this: g(y,z) = 0, (if y = 0 and z = 0) otherwise is g(y,z) = undefined, is that correct? Thanks in advance!

Case (i): $y = 0$.
In this case, $$g ( y , z ) = g ( 0 , z ) = \mu x . f ( x , 0 , z ) = \mu x. z . $$
So, if $z = 0$ then $g (y , z) = 0$ else $g ( y , z )$ is undefined.
Case (ii): $y > 0$.
In this case, for any $z \in \mathbb{N}$, $$ x = \left\lceil \frac{z}{y} \right\rceil $$ is the minimal solution of the equation $f ( x , y , z ) = 0$, where $ \left\lceil \cdot \right\rceil $ is the ceiling function.
So, $$ g ( y , z ) = \left\lceil \frac{z}{y} \right\rceil . $$

Thank you! So the cases of $g$ should be defined according to the 2 cases of the original function $f$. In the first case the term $z - x . y$ would be translated into the 2 defined cases you mentioned, and the last case of $f $ is the undefined one in $g$, right? Thanks again for the detailed answer.

Sorry, saying the last case of $f$ is the undefined case in $g$ sounds strange to me...
